# singleton implementation question

Tags: c++, boost

```
template <class T>
class Singleton 
{
public:
  static T& instance()
  {
    boost::call_once(init, flag);
    return *t;
  }

  static void init()
  {
    t.reset(new T());
  }

protected:
  ~Singleton() {}
   Singleton() {}

private:
   static boost::scoped_ptr <T> t;
   static boost::once_flag flag;
};

template <class T> boost::scoped_ptr<T> Singleton<T>::t(0); 
template <class T> boost::once_flag Singleton<T>::flag = BOOST_ONCE_INIT; 

class TestClass : public Singleton<TestClass>
{
  friend class Singleton<TestClass>;
  private:
     TestClass(){}
};
```

For the above implemenation, I have a question below:

```
TestClass class1 = TestClass::instance();  
TestClass class2 = TestClass::instance();
```

I found `&class1 != &class2`, is this a singleton?

Comment: [Singletons: Solving problems you didn’t know you never had since 1995](http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/03/singletons-solving-problems-you-didnt-know-you-never-had-since-1995/)

Comment: How did you create class1 and class2 objects? The constructor for MyClass is private.

Comment: If you can create two instances of it with different names, obviously not. I think you may want a private copy constructor.

Comment: It's a singleton ...NOT!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 TestClass class1 = TestClass::instance();
```

You're making a copy of the object returned by the factory, so you get a different object each time.

To prevent this, get *references* to your singleton:

```
 TestClass& class1 = TestClass::instance();
```

Still there is something strange because making a copy of MyClass issues compiler error (it inherit from `boost::noncopyable` via `Singleton`, so I'm not sure how you can compiled the code you posted.

Comment: Singleton is inheriting from boost::noncopyable, and MyClass is using the Singleton as a base class (it is really a CRTP). So, how do you know he is making a copy? He didn't post the code for the factory

Comment: @VJo: MyClass is a class type and there is no `&` nor `*` in the declaration, so it's creating a value. The question is why it compiles, because there is no copy constructor (it cannot be generated, because base-class copy constructor is not accessible).

Comment: @VJo Agree, it shouldn't compile.

Comment: if inherited from boost::noncopyable, I get the compilation error like cannot access private member declared in class 'boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable', so I do not inherited from boost:noncopyable, how to fix it? Also, change the pasted code

Comment: @user705414: You don't need to make `MyClass` inherit `boost:noncopyable`, it's already the case because Singleton inherits from it

Comment: I tried. if let singleton inherited from noncopyable, I received the error cannot access private member declared in class 'boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable', edit the question, basically it is my original code

Comment: The error is normal behaviour, it is "generated" by boost::noncopyable when you try to make a copy of the object. You don't want to copy your singleton instances returned by PerfEventFactory, replace `MyClass class1 = PerfEventFactory::instance();` by `MyClass& class1 = PerfEventFactory::instance();` and you'll be fine.

Comment: got it, Charles. Also, is it to recommended to use private inheritation from boost::noncopyable? Any reason for private inheritance here.

Comment: Yes, if you public inherit from it you won't get the errors that makes its functionnality